# Looping over the insert data into multiple tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query where I need to run to do manual inserts

I can do it but there are many records and was looking if I can build something.

I have a structure somewhat like this:

Have 4 id of a table - primary key values as:

```
var ids = "1,2,3,4";

loop over ids  {
    insert into table1(col1,col2,col3)  
    select col1,newid(),getdate() from table1 where id = ids - 1 at a time 

    var selectedID = get the id of the inserted row and then insert into anotehr table as: 

    insert into table2(col1,col2,col3,col4) 
    select selectedID, getdate(),getdate(),4 from table2 where fkID = ids - one at a time 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use both [loops](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/while-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) and [cursors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/declare-cursor-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) but often they can be avoided.

Is there a specific reason you note you want them inserted one at a time? An alternative would be to have the IDs staged, in a temp table, or CTE, e.g.

```
;WITH [Ids] AS
(
    SELECT '1' AS [ID]
    UNION 
    SELECT '2'
    UNION 
    SELECT '3'
    UNION 
    SELECT '4'
)
INSERT INTO [Table1]
(
    [Col1],
    [Col2],
    [Col3]
)
SELECT [Col1],
    NEWID(),
    GETDATE()
FROM [Table1] T
INNER JOIN [Ids] I ON I.[ID] = T.[Id];
```

Which avoids the need for any loops, and should perform much better.

**Edit**

The way I would structure this, to make the query reusable would be as follows:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#IDS') IS NOT NULL 
BEGIN 
    DROP TABLE #IDS
END

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Inserted_IDS') IS NOT NULL 
BEGIN 
    DROP TABLE #Inserted_IDS
END

CREATE TABLE #IDS
(
    ID INT
);

CREATE TABLE #Inserted_IDS
(
    ID INT,

);

INSERT INTO #IDS
(
    ID
)
SELECT 1 UNION
SELECT 2 UNION
SELECT 3 UNION
SELECT 4;

INSERT INTO [Table1]
(
    [Col1],
    [Col2],
    [Col3]
)
OUTPUT Inserted.ID
INTO #Inserted_IDS
SELECT [Col1],
    NEWID(),
    GETDATE()
FROM [Table1] T
INNER JOIN #IDS I ON I.[ID] = T.[Id];

INSERT INTO [table2]
(
    [col1],
    [col2],
    [col3],
    [col4]
) 
SELECT I.[ID],
    getdate(),
    getdate(),
    4 
FROM [#Inserted_IDS] I

DROP TABLE #IDS;
DROP TABLE #Inserted_IDS;
```

Therefore you only need to amend the IDs being entered into the temp table each time you need to do the inserts.

Comment: that is only involcing table1, how can i do it for table 2 all in one, a full working example will be best

Comment: do you get what is [selectedid], it is the value which should come from the above table new inserted value

Comment: @GMX I have updated my answer with the way I would approach this.

Comment: right, but in y question, i mentioned selectedID should be from the above inserted row of table 1

Comment: that did not worked, it inserted zero record in table 2

Comment: what is the TT, can you modify your example

Comment: @GMX I can, but you without your schema I will just have to guess what your ID is. Are they IDENTITY columns?

Comment: one is identity column which is table1, table2 has differentidentity, like pkid, but fkid is mapping the id of table 1

Comment: @GMK I have updated my answer, you will need to sub in the columns you need. I am also a little confused as to you second insert syntax, why are you using table 2, and matching the IDs, but selecting nothing from it? I don't see why it is needed.